# Extended ListView control with a filter boxes on the column headers

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, controls

I'm searching for extended ListView control with a filter boxes on the column headers - something like:

[image]

The image above is from DataGridExtensions WPF control, but I need a control for WinForms.

It will be excellent to have a control based on ListView, but any other help is appreciated (DataGrid-based control for example).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just use a third party that offers that if you don't want to go through the trouble of creating one, syncfusion seems to have a decent one (they offer a community licence as well) https://www.syncfusion.com/winforms-ui-controls/datagrid

Comment: The other option which I am not entirely positive if possible would be to use `WindowsXamlHost` from XAML island and host some uwp DataGrid control in it. Be aware that this is only supported in Forms projects that target .net core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it on your own by setting the ListView property `OwnerDrawn`.
Handle the `DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventHandler` and add your controls there. Then handle the changes and replace the ListView content by the filtered data. Or replace your backing data and refresh the control when you use `VirtualMode`.

If you want to use an existing, free control, I recommend to check on CodeProject. E.g.:

A simple one:[ListViewFilter Control for .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3610/ListViewFilter-Control-for-NET)

And a really sophisticated one: [A Much Easier to Use ListView](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2)

Comment: Thank you. [ListViewFilter Control for .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3610/ListViewFilter-Control-for-NET) looks suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[DataGridView-AutoFilter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataGridView-AutoFilter/) is a ready-made Nuget package, you just need to download it and follow this article, it is an easy and enhanced approach. DataGridView-AutoFilter [demo example](https://github.com/TelicSolutionsInc/DataGridViewAutoFilterDemo).